# I can't use VLC anymore

Tags: package-management, 16.04, vlc

After updating Ubuntu software 16.04 I couldn't use VLC player any more and then I removed VLC and tried to install it again and this showed:

> This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Does anyone know what should I do to repair VLC ?

[image]

Comment: How did you remove and reinstall VLC?

Comment: What does it say when you expand the `Details` section of that error message?

Comment: I removed it in ubuntu software center

Comment: Did you remove the Optional add-ons as well? You have to completely remove VLC before attempting to reinstall. To completely remove it from Ubuntu, close Ubuntu Software Center, open a Terminal window and type: `sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc`. The open (Gnome) Software and (re)install VLC. Ubuntu Software Center is no longer recommended for 16.04.

Comment: @ByteCommander
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2+git20160627+r58796+56~ubuntu16.04.1) but 2.2.2+git20160627+r58796+56~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 (>= 7:2.4) but 7:2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavutil-ffmpeg54 (>= 7:2.4) but 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16) but 2.23-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
     Depends: libegl1-x11 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0) but 1:5.2.1-22ubuntu2 is to be installed

Comment: @ByteCommander
Depends: libgles1 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libgles2 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0) but 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.4.2+dfsg-2ubuntu9 is to be installed
     Depends: libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but 5.4.2+dfsg-2ubuntu9 is to be installed
     Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.2.0) but 5.4.2+dfsg-2ubuntu9 is to be installed
     Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0) but 5.4.2-2build1 is to be installed

Comment: @ByteCommander
  Depends: librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4) but 2.40.13-3 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 5.2.1-22ubuntu2 is to be installed
     Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.6-1 is to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed

Comment: @ipselute I tried to install Gnome Software with : 
'**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/gnome-software** '
and '**sudo apt-get update**'
and it said:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @Lana Sorry, this information is nearly unreadable without proper formatting. Please remove your comments and [edit] your question to add it there, using code formatting. You should always put important additional information in the question so that it is better visible as well.

Comment: **Thank you all for your help, VLC is working now. :)**

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in terminal.

Issue the following command to get a list of the held packages:

`dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

Then issue the following command against each held package:

`echo "package_name install" | sudo dpkg --set-selection`

Now you should be able to install VLC with the following:

This makes sure your packages are up to date:

`sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade`

This removes any existing VLC install, including any configuration files:

`sudo apt-get purge vlc`

This installs VLC:

`sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: Another useful command is `sudo apt-get install -f` which tries to resolve dependency issues.

Comment: @Jibberish51 when I tried the last comand **sudo apt-get install vlc** it said :

_E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages._

Comment: Issue the command `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` to get a list of the held packages.

Then issue `echo "package_name install"|sudo dpkg --set-selections` on each **package_name** that is held

Comment: Source:         
[To get a list of held packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)         

[To release the hold on those packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @Lana: Well ,don't let us standing here like stupid dorks! Please help us with an exact answer of how you made it to work.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please consider clicking the little grey checkmark by it. It will mark the answer as "Solved" so it's easier for others to find, and it gives you some reputation as well!